# Buttons not visible on MasterDetailPage side bar

Tags: xamarin.forms

I got issue that my side bar's buttons which are at the bottom are not visible. I would like to have some scroolbar if there are more buttons than the size of screen to access them. How can i achieve that? Thank you.

**That's how it looks:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
<MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <ContentPage Padding="20" BackgroundColor="GhostWhite" Title="Master">
        <ContentPage.Content>
            <StackLayout Margin="5,30,5,5">

                <Label Text="NA" />
                <BoxView Color="Gray" HeightRequest = "2" />
                <Button Text="Tr" BackgroundColor="MidnightBlue" TextColor="White" Command="{Binding SetDetailsToTCommand}" />
                <Label Text="AKC" />
                <BoxView Color="Gray" HeightRequest = "2" />
                <Button Text="Zl" BackgroundColor="DarkBlue" TextColor="White" Command="{Binding SetDetailsToOCommand}" />
                <Button Text="In" BackgroundColor="DarkBlue" TextColor="White" Command="{Binding SetDetailsToInCommand}" IsVisible="{Binding IsBo}" />
                <Button Text="Po" BackgroundColor="Coral" TextColor="White" Command="{Binding SetDetailsToWanieCommand}" IsVisible="{Binding IsBo, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <Button Text="Re" BackgroundColor="Coral" TextColor="White" Command="{Binding SetDetailsToWaCommand}" IsVisible="{Binding IsBo, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <Button Text="Zw" BackgroundColor="Coral" TextColor="White" Command="{Binding SetDetailsToWaCommand}" IsVisible="{Binding IsBo, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <Label Text="GE" />
                <BoxView Color="Gray" HeightRequest = "2" />
                <Button Text="Wpi" BackgroundColor="DarkBlue" TextColor="White" Command="{Binding SetDetailsToWCommand}" IsVisible="{Binding IsBo, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <Label Text="OPCJ" />
                <BoxView Color="Gray" BackgroundColor="Red" HeightRequest = "2" />
                <Button Text="Zlec" BackgroundColor="Red" TextColor="White" Command="{Binding SetDetailsToOrRealizedCommand}" IsVisible="{Binding IsBo, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </StackLayout>
        </ContentPage.Content>
    </ContentPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Master>

<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <ContentPage Padding="10">
        <ContentPage.Content>
            <StackLayout Margin="5,30,5,5">
                <Label Text="Detail Page"
                       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                       HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
            </StackLayout>
        </ContentPage.Content>
    </ContentPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

Comment: Wrap your stacklayout in Master page with a ScrollVIew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest thing is to put everything inside a scroll view like -

```
<MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <ContentPage Padding="20" BackgroundColor="GhostWhite" Title="Master">
        <ContentPage.Content>
             <ScrollView>  <------------- HERE 
                 <StackLayout Margin="5,30,5,5">

                   <Label Text="NA" />
                   <BoxView Color="Gray" HeightRequest = "2" />
                   .
                   .
                   .
                </StackLayout>

             </ScrollView> <------------- HERE
        </ContentPage.Content>
    </ContentPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Master>
```

Else use a Grid layout to fit everything over the screen using '*' as Row Height

Comment: I will check it and let you know